# Is there a way I can point my sub-domain to AWS lightsail?

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I have a domain registered with Site-ground and created a sub-domain as well.

After that I created an AWS lightsail WordPress site that gave me an IP.

Now my question is, is there a way to point my sub-domain to AWS lightsail?

Answer (score 3):

Create a static IP in Lightsail, and attach it to your instance.

Update the DNS in siteground by creating an A record that maps the subdomain you want to the static IP in lightsail.

Comment: Definitely a good idea to create a static IP, as otherwise the IP address of your Lightsail instance will probably change if you reboot the instance.